# Why I haven't got right to kill a process from Windows' command prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, process

I'm studying C++ and I have to kill a process (my program I made).

But I cant see the process in the Task Manager so I googled how could I kill it from command prompt.

When I try to kill:

```
taskkill /IM mycpp.exe /f
```

It says I have no rights to do so. (Access denied)

I'm the only one using this computer, how could I give myself access to this killing command?

Comment: Run command prompt as Administrator?

Comment: How are you starting your process? Does your IDE/compiler... run as Administrator?

Comment: I ran cmd as Administrator, as of this, i should be easily terminate the process with no doubt.

Comment: what is the value for 'session' when you run `tasklist | findstr mycpp.exe` (note that case is important to findstr).

Comment: I dont know what is that but this is the output after this command:
1128 Console 1 20K

Comment: 'console'/'1' indicates that it was started by an process running in user-space, so you shouldn't need admin to kill it. any luck with `taskkill /PID 1128` ?

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi download process explorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), run it (Run As Administrator) and paste a screenshot of the entry for your exe in process explorer

Comment: QUOTE THE EXACT ERROR SO THAT IT IS GOOGLABLE THAT IS BASIC  also state the process itself, as maybe there is something others have run into regarding that process.

Comment: @Ganesh R. Pls make your comment as an answer and i will accept it. I can teminate the process with the program you adviced, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download [Sysinternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), run it (Run As Administrator). It will show you a list of user mode processes running on your system.

You can use it to terminate your process when you find it.

Alternatively, you can create a batch file and call [Sysinternals PSKill](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683.aspx) which allows you to specify an executable name which it then terminates. (The batch file may need to be run as Administrator)

Answer (score 0):

There are processes that will block attempts to be killed. Software like Antivirus will install drivers that will prevent you to kill it. Depending on version of Windows it might be possible to boot into safe mode and to kill task that way.